# How to make docker-compose build faster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build

I have two services in my `docker-compose.yaml` that use the same build context:

```
  service_1:
    image: 'service_1:latest'
    container_name: service_1
    env_file:
      - ./service_dir/.env
    ports:
        - "8000:80"
    build:
      context: ./service_dir/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./service_dir/app:/app
    command: /start-reload.sh

  service_2:
    container_name: service_2
    build:
      context: ./service_dir/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python app/my_script.py
```

Building this takes forever. I assume it has something to do with the fact that the build context is taken twice to the docker daemon? I'm not sure if these commands could be run in the same service but I'd prefer to have two separate containers so I can e.g. follow `service_2` logs more easily. Any suggestions for a good solution to my problem?

Comment: Do you know what part of the build sequence is slow?  Is it sending the build context, one of the Dockerfile steps, something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze this one is taking a really long time: `load metadata for docker.io/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9`. Which is strange because I've used that for a long time and have had no problems with it.